# Как работать с setEnabled на кнопку после onPause фрагмента?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-button

В моём фрагменте есть 3 поля - IP,логин и пароль + чекбокс. Есть функция isValid, которая проверяет данные поля на "адекватность" - то бишь валидация. Она возвращает true, если валидация успешно прошла и false если нет. В коде я применяю setEnabled(isValid()) на две кнопки. Так вот в самом фрагменте они работают адекватно, но если перейти на следующий фрагмент а потом вернуться по кнопке Back стандартной на телефоне, то кнопки будут недоступны, то есть isValid=false, хотя поля заполнены корректно, то есть должно быть true. 
setEnabled(isValid()) делаю в onCreateView. Как это пофиксить, что бы после возврата в этот фрагмент состояние кнопки обновлялось в зависимости от isValid() корректно. Извиняюсь за ломаный русский.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После возврата вызывается метод `onResume`, вот в нем и меняйте состояние кнопки

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}
```